# MySQL Join is multiplying the result

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I am having issues joining two tables together, it keeps multiplying my value "qtyFulfillable".

1st, when I run this query, I get the correct result: **sumQF = 85**

```
 SELECT fbai.id, 
        fbai.sku,
        CASE WHEN SUM(fbai.qtyFulfillable) > 0 THEN SUM(fbai.qtyFulfillable) ELSE 0 END AS sumQF
 FROM FBAInventory fbai
 WHERE fbai.fbaInventoryReport_id = 62010
 AND     fbai.sku = 'ELO-250030'
 GROUP BY fbai.id
 ORDER BY sumQF DESC
```

But when I start adding in the join, I now get: **sumQF = 14110**

```
 SELECT fbai.id, 
        fbai.sku,
        CASE WHEN SUM(fbai.qtyFulfillable) > 0 THEN SUM(fbai.qtyFulfillable) ELSE 0 END AS sumQF, 
        CASE WHEN   SUM(fbas.quantityShipped) > 0 THEN SUM(fbas.quantityShipped) ELSE 0 END as sumQS
 FROM FBAInventory fbai
 LEFT JOIN  FBAShipment fbas
 ON fbai.sku = fbas.sku
 WHERE fbai.fbaInventoryReport_id = 62010
 AND     fbai.sku = 'ELO-250030'
 GROUP BY fbai.id
 ORDER BY sumQF DESC
```

For some reason the sql taking the total number of rows in the "fbas" table (the joined table), 166 rows, and multiplying **85 x 166 = 14110**.

What do I need to do to be able to join in this table yet keep it from multiplying my result by the total number of rows in the joined table. Thanks!

Comment: Are you using MySQL or SQL Server? Please don't tag with two completely different database platforms unless you really are using both.

Comment: If FBAInventory has 85 records with SKU='ELO-250030', then for each of these 85 rows, it will try to join with the rows in FBAShipment  that have the same sku. There must be some other pair of fields that you want in your join's "ON" clause.

Comment: Does adding fbas.sku to the `GROUP BY` clause fix it? I.e. `GROUP BY fbai.id, fbas.sku`

Answer (score 0):

You could sum up the second quantity in a separate query and `JOIN` it in. I also like using `GREATEST` instead of your `CASE` statements.

```
    SELECT fbai.id,
           fbai.sku,
           GREATEST(SUM(fbai.qtyFulfillable),0) sumQF,
           COALESCE(fbas_sum.value,0) sumQS /* COALESCE in case no rows */
      FROM FBAInventory fbai
 LEFT JOIN (
        SELECT sku,
               GREATEST(SUM(quantityShipped),0) value
          FROM FBAShipment
      GROUP BY sku
           ) fbas_sum
        ON fbas_sum.sku=fbai.sku
     WHERE fbai.fbaInventoryReport_id=62010
       AND fbai.sku='ELO-250030'
  GROUP BY id, sku, sumQS /* Added other non-aggregates for sanity */
  ORDER BY sumQF DESC
```

Are you sure you want to group on `id` however? I would assume `id` is the primary key for the table so should only have one row to sum.